# event.trigger is not working

Tags: events, eventtrigger

event.trigger is not working only in the following case.

js file:

```
alert(event.target.getAttribute("name"));
```

html file:

```
            <div class=" tile  tile-big tile-5" id="three" name = "Launch" >
                <div><p>Launch Application </p></div>
            </div>
```

it is giving "null", not name.

and
     `alert(document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute("name"));` is working fine.

help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is your target is not

```
<div class=" tile  tile-big tile-5" id="three" name = "Launch" >
```

but

```
<p>Launch Application </p>
```

which does not have "name" attribute that is why you get null
try to add name attribute to it and you will get right alert.

try this

```
<div class=" tile  tile-big tile-5" id="three" name = "Launch" onclick="testAlert(event)">
            <div name = "Launch2"><p name = "Launch3">Launch Application </p></div>
</div>

<script>
function testAlert(event) 
{
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    alert(target.getAttribute('name'));
}
</script>
```

you will get the answer

Comment: that is usefull answer. but i want to get name of first div so this code `event.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("name");` is my required answer

Comment: yep, just be use it judiciously because
event.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("name")
is very fragile piece of code, because if you add another child node your code will no longer work